# How to convert tflite model to quantized model without pb file

Tags: python, bash, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to convert a tflite model to it's quantized version. (I try to convert the pose estimation module `multi_person_mobilenet_v1_075_float.tflite` hosted [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/hosted_models)) to it's quantized version. 
I therefore installed the `tflite_converter` command line tool, [recommended here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/cmdline_examples). But the examples do not fit my case where I only have a `*.tflite` file and no corresponding `frozen_graph.pb` file.

Thus when I just call

```
tflite_convert --output_file multi_person_quant.tflite  --saved_model_dir ./
```

from within the directory containing `multi_person_mobilenet_v1_075_float.tflite`, I get an error message:

```
IOError: SavedModel file does not exist at: .//{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

I guess I need a `.pb` file for whatever I want to do... Any idea how to generate it from the `*.tflite` file? 
Any other advice would also be helpful.